# how to find out which UIVIews are on the screen at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on an iPhone app that has a complex way of constructing its views, 
I am at a point where some of the UI behavior is not consistent and some UI views are not being presented properly,
without going into a lot of details, I am looking for a way at runtime to find out each and every UI element on the screen, and its location and whatever information I can get about it ( the UI stack, the layering, which UIVIew is on top of what ) is that available to developers/

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your question, try to access the UIWindow use an enumerator for loop to go though its subviews and print its frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In debug console, send `recursiveDescription` message to your topmost view.

```
(lldb) po [self.view recursiveDescription]
(id) $1 = 0x0929f000 <UIView: 0x944be30; frame = (0 20; 320 548); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x944be90>>
   | <UITableView: 0xab02800; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9449920>; layer = <CALayer: 0x944bc70>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x944c330; frame = (0 541; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x944c390>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x944c440; frame = (313 404; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x944c4e0>>
(lldb)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, now this output, the origin point in it is it for each view relative to its parent or to the screen? as in (0 0) i that top left of the phone for all views, or each view based on its parent?

Comment: frame is always relative to the parent view.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Spark Inspector Main View]

I'm the author of a tool called the [Spark Inspector](http://www.sparkinspector.com/) that allows you to view and interact with your app's UIViews while it's running. I put it together because I found myself using `-recursiveDescription` all the time and pouring over the console output was annoying—I think it's probably just what you need. Instead of calling `-recursiveDescription`, you add a framework to your app that lets the inspector tool connect and show you your views.

There are two other tools I'd recommend checking out as well: [PonyDebugger](https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger) and [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect). They take a bit more setup, but they're both lifesavers if you find yourself needing to debug views.